# How to make changes to custom formatter in WebStorm

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm

I would like to make change to custom formatter in WebStorm IDE. When i use [ctrl] + [alt] + [o] hotkey, my imports in TypeScript files are formated to form:

```
import {HttpModule} from "@angular/http";
```

It's ok, but TSLint highlight line and show message:

> TSLint: " should be ' (quotemark)

**Is it possible to change Webstorm custom formatter so that format imports in this way:**

```
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
```

I note that I'm not interested in changing tslint.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `Settings | Code Style | Typescript | Punctuation`, set **Use** to **single**.
Note that you can import code style prerefences from your `tslint.json` : open it in editor and click '*Yes*' when prompted to apply settings. See https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/01/webstorm-2017-1-eap-171-2455/, **Import code style from tslint.json**